# Upload file to S3 via multipart upload given temporary security credentials using AWS iOS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

My iOS application talks to a service(lets call this service "Service X") which is built on top of AWS. Service X provides RESTful APIs to upload content. When my application sends a PUT request to service X for creation of new asset, service X returns the information needed to perform multipart upload to S3. It contains "**access key**","**secret key**" & "**session token**" along with "**asset_arn**", "**upload id**" & "**S3 URL for multipart uploads**".

I am not sure how to use this information to perform multipart uploads using AWS iOS SDK. The SDK provides Cognito to manage credentials but i already have credentials with me. How can i proceed with this?

I can even use S3's REST API for performing multipart uploads but i am not sure how should i pass on the credential information.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Authentication/AWSCredentialsProvider.m and use your static credentials there. But I highly recommend you to use Cognito for credential management. Static credentials are dangerous for an app and should not be used in a production app.

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: What's a good way to manage credentials on a server, using a server side aws sdk?
For instance I'm on nodejs and using the corresponding sdk. But the ios sdk seems to be meant to work on his own, with things like Cognito, while I'd rather not mess up with that and have it handle credentials and authorizations with talking to my server.